# Extract object attribute from list of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js

I have the following object that I'm receiving from an API:

```
{
   '2012-12-12': [
       { 'id': 1234,
         'type': 'A' },
       { 'id': 1235,
         'type': 'A' },
       { 'id': 1236,
         'type': 'B' },
    ],
   '2012-12-13': [
       { 'id': 1237,
         'type': 'A' },
       { 'id': 1238,
         'type': 'C' },
       { 'id': 1239,
         'type': 'B' },
    ]
}
```

Then I want to have another variable named `types` of type `Array` that will hold every possible value of the `type` attribute of each one of the objects. In this case it would be:

```
types = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

I'm trying to have it done in a functional way (I'm using underscore.js) but I'm unable to figure out a way of doing it. Right now I'm using

```
types = [];
_.each(response, function(arr1, key1) {
    _.each(arr1, function(arr2, key2) {
        types.push(arr2.type);
    });
});
types = _.uniq(types);
```

But that's very ugly. Can you help me in figuring out a better way of writing this code?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code is clear. There is no problem with it in my opinion.

Comment: You could keep a separate "typeMap" variable, whose value would start as just a simple object (`{}`).  Then you can use it as a way to keep track of types you've already seen.

Comment: @dystroy if the original object is large and the number of types is small, there's some unnecessary work done, but I agree it's probably not really a bad thing at small scale.

Comment: @Pointy yes, that would be an optimization, but probably not really useful.

Comment: I'd change the name of `arr2` as it's actually an `object` in this case, but that's more developer empathy than functional improvement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
types = _.chain(input) // enable chaining
  .values()            // object to array
  .flatten()           // 2D array to 1D array
  .pluck("type")       // pick one property from each element
  .uniq()              // only the unique values
  .value()             // get an unwrapped array
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NFSfs/

Of course, you can remove all whitespace if you want to:

```
types = _.chain(input).values().flatten().pluck("type").uniq().value()
```

or without chaining:

```
types = _.uniq(_.pluck(_.flatten(_.values(input)),"type"));
```

---

[flatten seems to work on objects](http://jsbin.com/ewopeh/1), even though [the documentation clearly states it shouldn't](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten). If you wish to code against implementation, you can leave out the call to `values`, but I don't recommend that. The implementation could change one day, leaving your code mysteriously broken.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want shorter code, you could flatten the objects into a single Array, then map that Array.

```
var types = _.unique(_.map(_.flatten(_.toArray(response)), function(arr) {
    return arr.type;
}));
```

---

Here's another version. Mostly just for curiosity's sake.

```
var types = _.unique(_.pluck(_.reduce(response, _.bind(Function.apply, [].concat), []), "type"));
```

---

Here's another one.

```
var types = _.unique(_.reduce(response, function(acc, arr) {
    return acc.concat(_.pluck(arr,"type"));
}, []));
```

---

And another.

```
var types = _.unique(_.pluck([].concat.apply([], _.toArray(response)), "type"))
```

Comment: I don't think you can `flatten` an object

Comment: @JanDvorak: You're right. The source shows that it only performs a type check on the values, not the outer structure, so because `each()` is used on the outer structure, there's no complaint. And since it creates a new Array instead of modifying the original, the `.push()`s succeed. But the docs clearly require an array.