# Filter array of objects by object key

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array of objects in Javascript:

```
var List = [
            {
                employee:'Joe',
                type:'holiday',
            },
            {
                employee:'Jerry',
                type:'seminar',

            },
            {
                employee:'Joe',
                type:'shore leave',
            }
           ];
```

I would like to obtain two new arrays of objects; one for the key employee "Joe" and the other for the key employee "Jerry". The objects should keep the same pairs of key/values.

I have been trying to get a solution using underscore.js, but it is getting too complicated. Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Do you want to provide the names or do you want to group the object automatically by  name? Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: `_.groupBy` and `_.pluck`, most likely.

Comment: [Extract object attribute from list of objects in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842282/extract-object-attribute-from-list-of-objects-in-javascript/14842426#14842426)

Comment: There are 2 `"Joe"`s.  What do you want the result to look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var emps = {};  
_.each(List, function(item){
   emps[item.employee] = emps[item.employee] || [];
   emps[item.employee].push(item);
});
```

or using `groupBy`

```
var emps = _.groupBy(List, function(item){
   return item.employee;
});
```

`console.log(emps);` gives

```
{
    "Jerry": [
        {
            "employee": "Jerry",
            "type": "seminar"
        }
    ],
    "Joe": [
        {
            "employee": "Joe",
            "type": "holiday"
        },
        {
            "employee": "Joe",
            "type": "shore leave"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var joe = List.filter(function(el){
 return el.employee === "Joe"
});

var jerry = List.filter(function(el){
 return el.employee === "Jerry"
});
```

This uses [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and will work in IE9 and up + all recent Chrome/Firefox/Safari/Opera releases.

If you don't know the names in advance then you can create a map
var names = {};

```
for(var i =0; i<List.length; i++){
  var ename = List[i].employee;
  if(typeof names[ename] === "undefined"){
     names[ename] = List.filter(function(el){
     return el.employee === "ename"
    });
   }
```

}

As a side note, Javascript convention is to only capitalize the first letter of a variable for constructors.  So List should probably be list.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - I don't have the rep. to comment yet but I believe it should be

```
return el.employee === ename;  // No quotes around ename
```

Otherwise the answer @Ben gives is perfect - it can be extended into a 'groupby' function if using underscore is out of the question a the project.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, there is also Underscore's version of [`_.filter`](https://underscorejs.org/#filter) which works with the [`_.matcher`](https://underscorejs.org/#matcher) iteratee [shorthand](https://underscorejs.org/#iteratee). This is essentially a much shorter version of Ben McCormick's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15274750/1166087).

```
var joe = _.filter(List, {employee: 'Joe'});
var jerry = _.filter(List, {employee: 'Jerry'});
```